# Passing data thru RxJs operators

Tags: rxjs

while learning some RxJs I came about this problem. I start my operator chain with an object and use ooe of it's properties to do an AJAX request using flatmap but I need the other object's properties passed along with the Ajax result. I came with the following solution, but I'm sure there must be a way more elegant or efficient solution to it. Any Idea on how to improve the code?

```
function fbInfo(ezfb){
const fbItems$ = Rx.Observable.from(lista)
    .map(item => Object.assign( {}, item, {query: `/${item.page}/feed?limit=1`}))
    .do(x=>console.log(x))
    .flatMap(item => {
        return  Rx.Observable.fromPromise(ezfb.getLoginStatus().then((res)=>{return ezfb.api(item.query)}))
                .withLatestFrom(Rx.Observable.from([item]),(res, it)=> Object.assign({}, res, it))
    }).map(item => { return {            
        mensaje: item.data[0].message,
        id: item.data[0].id,
        created: item.data[0].created_time,
        nombre: item.nombre
        }
    })
return fbItems$
}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

In terms of general patterns, I know of no cleaner way than carrying anything you want to keep through each step (as you have). In terms of specific syntax, yes, there are shorter ways to express what you want. The awkward `=> { return { ... } }` syntax can be replaced with `=> ({ ... })`. Unless you really need the properties on the root of the same object, you could do away with `Object.assign`. But the flow of data would essentially be the same.